# Error: There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

I've checked my values but it still says that I do not have enough. I have one value that isn't in the insert-statement but it's an identity-value, so I guess I don't have to specify that in my code?!?!

Anyway here's the code:

```
string Fname = tbFIRSTNAME.Text.Trim();
                string Lname = tbLASTNAME.Text.Trim();
                string Sname = tbStreetName.Text.Trim();
                string SSN = tbSSN.Text.Trim();
                string CrimeID = cmbCRIMEID.Text.ToString();
                string DangerLVL = cmbDANGERLEVEL.Text.ToString();
                string CrimeDesc = rtbCrimeInfo.Text.Trim();

                string str = "insert into Crooks (FirstName, LastName, StreetName, SSN, CrimeID, DangerLevel, CrimeDescription) values ('" + Fname + '"' + Lname + '"' + Sname + '"' + SSN + '"' + DangerLVL + '"' + CrimeID + '"' + CrimeDesc + "')";

                clsDB.InsUpDel(str);
```

Comment: You aren't separating the values by comma...They are all being inserted as one value

Comment: Where are the commas `,` between the values?

Comment: You may want to consider adding parameters to your SQL statement to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: Thanks! And don't worry about the injections, i won't be using this one.

Comment: Put in a breakpoint and look at what's actually in `str`. It's not just missing the commas. You also have exactly one quotation mark in between each value and the next. It'll look like `"Joe"Blogs"Mulberry"123-456-7890"``. There's no language where that's valid.

Comment: SQL Parameters are about more than SQL injection.  If `tbLASTNAME.Text` has something like `O'Toole` or `D'Agastino` your code will crash; they also prevent everything from being passed as string as you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't set comma between your values (So you are actually entering one value not 7):

```
string str = "insert into Crooks (FirstName, LastName, StreetName, SSN, CrimeID, DangerLevel, CrimeDescription) values ('" + Fname + "','" + Lname + "','" + Sname + "'," + SSN + "," + DangerLVL + "," + CrimeID + ",'" + CrimeDesc + "')";
```

Clearly some of varchar types are not enclosed between `''` too. this is not the case right now, but after adding commas you may get other errors because of type mismatches

Answer (score 2):

Your basic error, as others stated, is that you are not separating all the values with commas.
Apart from that, you have a big security flaw. And that is to use your values directly from your textboxes. That is the most insecure and most common security flaw in software design and will potentially lead you to have SQL Injection attacks to your application. To avoid that, you should use parametrized query. This is a resumed code, but you should so something like this:

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "insert into Crooks (FirstName, LastName, StreetName, SSN, CrimeID, DangerLevel, CrimeDescription) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @StreetName, @SSN, @CrimeID, @DangerLevel, @CrimeDescription)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", tbLASTNAME.Text.Trim());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", tbStreetName.Text.Trim());
        /*
        ...
        AND SO ON WITH OTHER PARAMETERS
        ...
        */    
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this.